# TypeError while tokenizing a column in Spark dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark

I'm trying to tokenize a 'string' column from a spark dataset.

The spark dataframe is as follows:

```
df: 
index ---> Integer 
question ---> String
```

This is how I'm using the spark tokenizer:

```
Quest = df.withColumn("question", col("Question").cast(StringType()))
tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol=Quest, outputCol="question_parts")
```

But I get the following error:

> Invalid param value given for param "inputCol". Could not convert
> <class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'> to string type

I also substituted the first line of my code with following codes, but they didn't resolve this error either:

```
Quest = df.select(concat_ws(" ",col("question")))
```

and

```
Quest= df.withColumn("question", concat_ws(" ",col("question")))
```

What's my mistake here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is the second line. `df.withColumn()` returns a dataframe with the column you just created appended. In the second line, `inputCol="question"` should give you what you need. You then need to transform your dataframe using the tokenizer.

Try:

```py
df = df.withColumn("Question", col("Question").cast(StringType()))
tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol="Question", outputCol="question_parts")
tokenizer.Transform(df)
```

Edit:
I'm not sure you intended to create a new column in the first line - I've changed the column name in the `withColumn` method from `"question"` to `"Question"` to replace the existing column. It also looks from your data like the column is already in string format - if so this step is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem. Just to make sure I understood it, in the code you suggested, the 1st line changes the type of a single column in the df to String; the 2nd line feeds that line to the tokenizer; and the 3rd line transforms the df. Am I correct? Also, if I am correct, then why not just transform that single column ('Question) instead of the whole df? Is there a way?

Comment: The second line here is creating the tokenizer - it doesn't know anything of your dataframe. It is independent of the first line, and the order of those 2 doesn't matter. It could tokenize the a string column named "Question" in any dataframe. This behaviour is useful when using ML pipelines (see the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-pipeline.html)).

Comment: When the dataframe is transformed, really what you get is a new column appended with the tokenized values. It doesn't transform every column, just the `inputCol` you specified in the Tokenizer.